# Any help on getting the city or zip codes that make up metropolitan statistical areas?

Tags: data-request, postal-code, usa

I have a list of addresses (city, state, zip) and I'd like to group them into regions throughout the united states.

It seems that metro/micropolitan statistical areas is a good way of doing that, but I'm having a hard time finding a list of all the zip codes and which area they fall into or city/state per statistical area.

Any leads? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Here are the resources for other people --

The CBSAs -- 
http://osav-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b0d0e777e2ad4b53803dbc0527c73d88_0

The crosswalk from zip to CBSA -- 
https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/usps_crosswalk.html

The population data for each CBSA -- 
https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2016/demo/popest/total-metro-and-micro-statistical-areas.html

The key for understanding the CBSA file --
http://planning.maryland.gov/msdc/census/cen2010/MetroAreaMap/ShapeFile/zipfile_idx.shtml

Credit goes to another stackexchange post for linking to the HUD website. Who hudda thunk it?